# What would happen if Carbon-14 was in a molecule, and decayed into Nitrogen?

Tags: biochemistry, radioactivity

This interested me because of Melvin Calvin's experiment with photosynthesis where he used radioactive Carbon-14. If a plant used it as a reactant to make glucose, and that Carbon-14 decayed into nitrogen, what would happen to the molecule?

Comment: I'm closing this question as it was cross-posted to [biology.se](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/42239). Please consider removing the duplicate and flag for reopening.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I think this is more of chemistry than biology. Vote on close by this one: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42239/what-would-happen-if-carbon-14-was-in-a-glucose-molecule-and-decayed-into-nitrog

Comment: @inf3rno It does not matter if it is about biology or chemistry, as long as there are two identical posts in the network. I closed it as a courtesy to our partner site. This community can still decide if it is on or off-topic. The question here, should/will only be reopened if it is deleted at biology.se.